# Error: ' Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" ' in combination with google recaptcha v2. Works on local machine but not on webhost

Tags: perl, hash, recaptcha

I am very new to Perl and was just assigned the quick task to change the reCAPTCHA to reCAPTCHA v2.

On my local machine this works fine, however when I push the new version of the login form to the webhost, the form does not seem to work. I get the following error:

AH01215: Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at login_new.cgi line 68,  line 1.: [........]

The code snippet is based on the documentation I found here: https://metacpan.org/pod/Captcha::reCAPTCHA::V2

And according to the error log my error is somewhere in here (line 68):

```
if ($submit) {
    my $response = $cgi->param('g-recaptcha-response');
    my $result = $captcha->verify($captcha_private_key, $response );

    if ($result->{success})  # This is line 68
    {....}
```

This is quite confusing to me, especially since it is working on my local machine. Could you please help? Best regards and thank you in advance!

Comment: Just a little help with tracing back: how can the result of method `verify` be an empty string? https://metacpan.org/source/PATTAWAN/Captcha-reCAPTCHA-V2-0.3/lib/Captcha/reCAPTCHA/V2.pm#L72 When `post_form` returns an empty string. https://metacpan.org/source/DAGOLDEN/HTTP-Tiny-0.070/lib/HTTP/Tiny.pm#L417

Comment: Thank you for your hint, daxim. I will look further into this issue. What confuses me is the fact that it works on my machine but not on the webserver. Maybe I have to request some help from the webhost. Greetings to Austria from Germany.
derhendrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Verify Function has a bug. I just looked at the implementation. in case that "$res" isn't 'successful' it wont give you back the wanted hash reference.

As a quick workaround I would check if your `my $result` is equal to `""` if thats the case the verify function failed.
In the long run you should probably submit that bug to the creator of the module.

**disclaimer: I havent downloaded the module and just looked at the source without actually trying my workaround so take it with a grain of salt and try it in a safe environment first**

```
sub verify {
    my ($self, $secret, $response, $remoteip) = @_;

    # ... more code here, removed for better readability

    my $res = $self->{ua}->post_form(
        $self->{verify_api},
        $params
    );

    if ($res->{success}) {
        my $content = decode_json $res->{content};
        if ($content->{success}){
            return { success => 1 };
        } else {
            return { success => 0, error_codes => $content->{'error-codes'} };
        }
    }
}
```